# Can't run matplotlib with cmd

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to make some graphs with `matplot`, I installed it with `pip install matlotlib`, I ran a few commands in `python.exe`, everything was working fine, I got the graph but then I made a script file `hello_matplot.py` I launched it through the `cmd` and I got this:

```
No module named matplot lib
```

How can I resolve this problem, if I have to add the library to my `PATH`, how do I find where is the location of this `matplotlib` ?

Comment: You should not have to add it to the path given that python imports it from its own library folder, not the OS. I presume there is another issue.

Comment: I have anaconda3, I am new to Python I don't really know what it is but.. can that be the problem ?

Comment: I am sorry then I can't be much of a help about anaconda3, I thought you were using windows.

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Forgive me then, you sure your code is running using python.exe or IDLE, and just not working in cmd ?

Comment: yes, tried using `cmd` -> `python` type the code, it works when i double click my file, it doesn't work

Comment: damn, now it suddenly stopped working on python.exe as well..

Comment: Pleaase check your code again. Make sure you got the module name right.

Comment: i did, it's good `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: you have the latest version of matplotlib right ?

Comment: 1.5.1  I just reinstalled it's working again for python.exe but not for the script

Comment: Are you sure you did `conda install matplotlib` and can you please post the import part of this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to make sure you are using the full file path in cmd... C:/file.py *EXAMPLE*

When trying to find matplotlib, you can always go to your environment variables in system control panel to find the library...

Comment: In cmd I am in the needed folder

Comment: matplotlib is not in the environment variables, that is the problem, I can't seem to find it in the PATH

Comment: does your script start with this "#!/usr/bin/env python"

Comment: Make sure you installed python3-matplotlib and not install python-matplotlib

Comment: C:\Users\hp\Documents\Github\summer-2016\Pitonia\hello_mat.py

Comment: If you are in the folder then just run the file

Comment: alright which version of matplotlib and python are installed

Comment: Is python3-matplotlib installed

Comment: what version of python is installed

Comment: python 3.5. I have no duplicates

Comment: didi you install python3-matplotlib or python-matplotlib

Comment: I got it, I have 2 versions of python ... one of which is 3.6, on which it's not working and one which is 3.5 from Anaconda(on which is working)

Comment: Are both versions of python in your environment variables?

Comment: control panel> system> advanced system settings> environment variables> Path - to check

Comment: yeah, i removed the one on which is not working I changed it in the registry butstill

Comment: Apparently, matplotlib is not really compatible with python 3, but it does work.  In python 2.7, it works the best..

Comment: fixed it, just changed the version of my default python, thank you :)